# How to display a substring in a Button

Tags: android, arrays, textview

I have a String value called `String names;`which is received by a ble device.
I need to display its substring to a textview named line2.
But it shows nothing, How can i achieve this.

My code is.

```
String names;
String i=(names.substring(1, 2));
String.valueOf(i);
line2.setText(i);
```

Comment: what does names contain.

Comment: name contains date and time as "0102151200"

Comment: What happens when you run your app? Does it crash? If its a string you can display it. But if its a integer use `line2.setText(String.valueOf(i));` and look @ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29

Comment: no it wont crash. but the textview becomes blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to use your methods with a assigned value for names variable- like String names = "0102151200". If it works, then there is some problem in your program which is not assigning value in your names variable.